# How do I access groups of a user in a parent domain?

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

I'm working in an instance where there are two AD domains Dom1 and Dom2.  There is a one way trust from the Dom1 to the Dom2 so that users in Dom1 can be authorized in Dom2.

My c# code does this just fine.

However, in Dom2 when I go to pull the user's groups from a user in Dom1 I don't get anything.  I do get a list of groups from users that exist in Dom2.

```
            _DE.Path = "LDAP://RootDSE";
        string szDomain = (string)_DE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0];
        string obEntry = "LDAP://" + szDomain;
        SearchResult res = ADExists("UserPrincipalName=" + szUPN, "User");
        try
        {
            if (res != null)
            {
                _DE.Path = res.Path;
                //szUserDN = res.Path;
                if (_DE.Properties["memberOf"].Count > 1)
                {
                    object[] groups = (object[])_DE.Properties["memberOf"].Value;
                    if (groups != null)
                    {
                        foreach (object group in groups)
                        {
                            string szGroup = group.ToString();
                            DataRow drAdd = dtGroups.NewRow();
                            drAdd["GroupName"] = group;
                            dtGroups.Rows.Add(drAdd);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace instead:

```
static GroupPrincipal[] GetUserAuthorisationGroups(string userPrincipalName)
{
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userPrincipalName))
    {
        return user.GetAuthorizationGroups().OfType<GroupPrincipal>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can find groups by whatever way you want:

```
GroupPrincipal[] groups = GetUserAuthorisationGroups(szUPN);

bool searchBySid = groups.Any(g => g.Sid == groupSid);
bool searchByDN = groups.Any(g => g.DistinguishedName == groupDN);
bool searchByName = groups.Any(g => g.Name == groupName);
```

Comment: Still has an issue with finding the user.  The line that seems to be an issue is the using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByItentity......);

Comment: @ScottJohnson Is `szUPN` an actual fully qualified UPN, so `username@domain.local` or whatever the dns domain name is?

Comment: Yes, it would look like username@domain.local

Comment: I can authorize the user on the from the one way trusted domain but I can't find / access the user even if I specify the location of the user...